# separating key and multiple values for print with .each

Tags: ruby

I'm probably trying to be hard headed about this. I'm trying to format hash key and and array of values for output to user. Ruby-doc give me the code for it for one value. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002861

```
h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h.each {|key, value| puts "#{key} is #{value}" }
```

I'm trying to get

```
h = { "a" => [100,'green'], "b" => [200,'red'] }
h.each {|key, m,n| puts "#{key} is #{m} and #{n}"}  

produces: 

a is 100 and green
b is 200 and red
```

I've had some luck with 
    h.each{|key,m,n| puts "#{key} is #{[m,'n']} "}

```
it produces:

a is 100green
b is 200red
```

I need some space between my array of elements, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 7):

```
h.each {|key, (m, n)| puts "#{key} is #{m} and #{n}"}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
h.each { |key, value| puts "#{key} is #{value.first} and #{value.last}" }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of [`each_pair`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Hash.html#M000175) for hashes:

```
h.each_pair {|key, val| puts "#{key} is #{val[0]} and #{val[1]}" }
```

Or

```
h.each_pair {|key, val| puts "#{key} is #{val.join(' and ')}"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h.each {|k,v| puts "#{k} is #{v[0]} and #{v[1]}"}
```